# Yii CGridView Sort for array as dataProvider

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have an array as my dataProvider ( I have set up the custom filter method too ) and it looks and works just fine:

[image]

but now, for responsive purposes, I need to remove filters on small devices, which I have accomplish like this:

```
, 'htmlOptions' => array( 'class' => 'hidden-sm hidden-xs hidden-md' )
, 'headerHtmlOptions' => array( 'class' => 'hidden-sm hidden-xs hidden-md' )
, 'filterHtmlOptions' => array( 'class' => 'hidden-sm hidden-xs hidden-md' )
```

and add sorting buttons, like these:

[image]

**How do I add the sort option with a custom sort image?**

*I can post the full GridView code, but it is a bit long ( hence the custom columns )*

*UPDATE*

That's how my dataProvider last script looks like:

```
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['FiltersForm'] ) )
    $filtersForm->filters = $_REQUEST['FiltersForm'];

# Get rawData and create dataProvider
$filteredData = $filtersForm->filter( $model->results['company'] );
$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider( $filteredData );

# Render
$this->render( 'results', array(
    'filtersForm' => $filtersForm,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'model' => $model
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Csort**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSort).

In controller setup Dataprovider using Csort, [**Example**](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/8784-cgridview-sort-columns/)

```
public function actionIndex(){
  $sort = new CSort();
  $sort->attributes = array(
    'customer'=>array(
    'asc'=>'customer.customer_name',
    'desc'=>'customer.customer_name desc',
  ),

  'school'=>array(
    'asc'=>'school.school_name',
    'desc'=>'school.school_name desc',
  ),
    'submitted_date',
    'requested_date',
 );

  $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Printjob', array(
   'criteria'=>array(
   'alias'=>'pj',
   'join'=>'inner join customer on customer.customer_id=pj.customer_id inner join school on school.school_id=pj.school_id',
),
'sort'=>$sort,
'pagination'=>array(
  'pageSize'=>self::PAGE_SIZE,
),
));
$this->render('index',array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider));
```

Comment: Ok, if I understand it correctly, then I need to define each columns sort type in my Controller and then ... (check my updated question)

Comment: I'm still lost, I'm not getting the data from database, I get it from a soap request. After that, I turn it into an ordinary array and work with that. I do know, that I miss something very simple and that's why I'm trying to find out what it is.

Comment: Try without soap and check,than you can debug.

Comment: There is no difference in that